# I don't see the hole in the lens getting bigger or smaller, so is it damaged?

Tags: lens, aperture, camera-settings

Just started learning photography and ordered a *35mm f1.8G ED Nikon* lens. I understand it is a prime lens, and doesn't zoom in or out, but the `f number` there doesn't show any change from `1.8` when I look through the viewfinder and read the metrics. I start turning the thingy on the lens and it changes the focus, but still I don't see that number getting changed from 1.8 on the viewfinder metrics.

I was under impression that it should change and if I take out the lens from camera and again turn that thingy on the lens I don't see the hole getting bigger or smaller. I thought that is called "aperture" but it doesn't change. So is it a broken lens and should return it?

I was under "Aperture priority mode" of the camera for numbers above, now I switched to "Automatic mode" and the number shows as `4` now. But still when I go to "Aperture priority" mode, **it is stuck on 1.8**. So does it mean the lens is damaged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "thingy" you can turn on the lens is a focus dial. Most modern lenses don't have a separate manual aperture control, instead relying on the body for automatic aperture setting. And even if the lens supported manual aperture control, except for on very, very old lenses, the aperture diaphram stays open until you press the shutter, at which point it is quickly "stopped down" to the selected value.

It sounds like everything is fine, really. If the photos taken in automatic mode appear to be exposed correctly, I wouldn't worry. If, on the other hand, they are far too bright, it's possible that the aperture is physically stuck — but nothing you've said indicates that that's likely.

In aperture priority mode, you set the aperture by changing the dial (varies from camera to camera exactly where, of course, but on Nikon entry-level bodies, it's the dial on the back at the top right; on higher-end Nikons, it defaults to the *front* dial). This should change the number you see in the viewfinder, and you should also see the shutter speed change to match the meter reading. Again, if the aperture is stuck, try turning it down to a small aperture (high f number — like, f/22). This should result in a long shutter speed (unless the scene is very, very bright). If the aperture is stuck open, you'll get a *very* overexposed result in that case.

Comment: Thanks for info. Hmm now I wonder how these guys in video tutorials were showing the hole getting bigger and smaller.

Comment: Well one question then: So when we put the camera on "A" mode, doesn't it mean we should be able to manually change the Aperture?

Comment: I'm not sure about the video tutorial — not my area. I assume that in video mode, it's easy to see, since the aperture is likely held constant while recording to avoid brightness and depth of field shifts.

Comment: And yes, you should definitely be able to change the aperture in aperture priority mode. (That's `A` on Nikon cameras, `Av` on Pentax or Canon.) The manual for the camera should tell you how if the above doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks but that's what I meant to ask, I put it in Aperture mode, I turn that dial and the value does not change from 1.8

Comment: Hmmm. What camera model?

Comment: It is Nikon D-610

Comment: @user1899082 Okay, maybe this is too obvious, but have you tried the _front_ dial? (See page 77 of the [manual](http://download3.nikonimglib.com/archive1/3PBoc00MJ7vb00PxKru74a9gED26/D610_NT%28En%2901.pdf).)

Comment: Aweome! Yep that was it :) Thanks Matt, hadn't seen that dial button yet! It is just a few days I got the camera. I was dialing the other one that is on the back of the camera, that one changes exposure, iso, etc...

Comment: @user1899082 Heh. Glad I could help. See also page 245 — you can flip which dial does what, if you like.

Comment: Eventually, you'll come to know and appreciate all those various dials. Or, at least, I do. The steep learning curve pays off eventually in faster and more intuitive adjustments on the fly when you're shooting.

Comment: @user1899082: They might have been using bulb mode

Comment: @PlasmaHH or a D lens, rather than a G. :) G lenses don't have aperture rings, D lenses do.  And if you push a DoF preview button, then the lens will actually stop down.

Answer (score 3):

The hole stays wide open to let in the maximum amount of light when you're composing and focussing. The hole closes down to the specified aperture value *at the moment the shot is being taken*. That's a feature, not a bug.